# SQL query to pull out form entries where each value is a separate row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a models for a user built form as follows:

```
Form
  id
  title

FormField
  id
  type
  name
  label

FormEntry
  id
  form_id
  date

FormFieldEntry
  id
  form_entry_id
  form_field_id
  value
```

I am trying to formulate a sql query on Form that will have the FormField labels as column names and the FormFieldEntry's as the values.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? You're basically asking for a "dynamic pivot" here.

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli: I am using MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to accomplish what you seek is to use dynamic SQL. You must assemble the SQL statement string in code by querying for the column names and send it to the database. The resulting SQL statement you build might look something like:

```
Select FFE.form_entry_id
    , Min( Case When FF.name = 'Foo' Then FFE.value End ) As `Foo`
    , Min( Case When FF.name = 'Bar' Then FFE.value End ) As `Bar`
    , ...
From FormFieldEntry As FFE
    Join FormField As FF
        On FF.id = FFE.form_field_id
Group By FFE.form_entry_id
```